# How to remove numbering in TOC from pdfpages

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

How can I remove the numbering of section of an icluded pdf on the table of contents. The picture shows what I have on the top and what I want on the bottom. I want it to appear the included pdf on te TOC as P05-001, without 9. Here is the code:

```
\chapter*{Anexo: Procedimientos}
\label{anexo:Procedimientos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexo: Procedimientos}
\markboth{Anexo: Procedimientos}{}
\includepdf[pages={-},addtotoc={1, section, 2, P05-001, P05-001}, scale=0.7, pagecommand={}]{pdf/proc_2015/p05_001_2015.pdf}
```

[image]

Comment: I don´t want to edit the pdf, I want to edit the TOC

Comment: sorry I misread your example (easily done when it's a fragment that can't be used locally) I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the `\backmatter` chapters are not numbered, but go automatically in the table of contents; so if you have several of these “anexos”, it's better to use this feature.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Blurb}

\section{Blurb blurb}

\backmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} % no level is numbered

\chapter{Anexo: Procedimientos}

\includepdf[
  pages={-},
  addtotoc={1, section, 2, P05-001, P05-001},
  scale=0.7,
  pagecommand={}
]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]